# How prove this integral with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}$ indentity

Tags: calculus, integration

> show that
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(\cot{\dfrac{x}{4}}\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}f\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin{x}}\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$$

I want prove following
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(f\left(\cot{\dfrac{x}{4}}\right)-f\left(\dfrac{1}{\sin{x}}\right)\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx=I_{1}-I_{2}=0$$
for 
$$I_{1}=\left(\int_{0}^{\pi/2}+\int_{{\pi/2}}^{\pi}\right)f\left(\cot{\dfrac{x}{4}}\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx=A+B$$
for $B$,we let $x=\pi-u$
$$B=\int_{0}^{{\pi/2}}f\left(\dfrac{1+\tan{u}}{1-\tan{u}}\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{u}}}du=\int_{0}^{{\pi/2}}f\left(\tan{\left(\frac\pi4+x\right)}\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$$
so
$$I_{1}=\int_{0}^{{\pi/2}}\left(f\left(\cot{\dfrac{x}{4}}\right)+f\left(\tan{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+x\right)}\right)\right)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}dx$$

follow I can't work, can you help me ?

why closed it? can you explain?

Comment: "You can't" what? Add some personal input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change of variables $\theta=\arcsin(\tan(x/4))$ shows that
$$\int_0^\pi f\left(\cot\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}}
=2\int_0^{\pi/2} f\left( \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \right)\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin \theta}}
=\int_0^{\pi} f\left( \frac{1}{\sin\theta} \right)\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin \theta}}.$$